# Unexpected error on declaring vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm getting an unexpectred error when I initialize a vector in the main. 
I was expecting the following output:

```
0 1 2
```

I can't see why it's not working. I also writed the same code in another pc using the same compiler, and it works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vett = {0,1,2};
    for (int i : vett) {
    cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
error: could not convert '{0, 1, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<int>'|
```

Comment: Do you have C++11 or higher enabled?

Comment: Is that the *only* error you get? How do you build your program? With what compiler? What version of the compiler? What flags and options do you use when building?

Comment: Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile with at least C++11. [List initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) came with C++11.

-std=c++11

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling with something older than C++11, it does not support initializer list constructor.

If you are using Code::Blocks follow these steps:

Settings -> compiler -> compiler flags -> select C++11 or above